# How do I stop my model from warping horrifically when bones are rotated?

Tags: rigging, bones, rigify

I'm new to using Blender to make models, and wanted to make a custom VRChat model as a test of skills and even if I have the capacity to upload a model (and be Quest viable). I've watched dozens of tutorials but just can't seem to understand how this works.

So, I rig up my bones and try to scale them and move them around to match proportions. (I used my Roblox avatar so that way I didn't have to make a custom model from scratch.)

When in default pose? It works just fine, no questions asked.
[image: perfectly normal roblox avatar, nothing to see here]

But the very MINUTE I try to rotate any bone in any direction...
[image: a not so normal roblox avatar, warped and skewed]

I have a vague idea on how this happened, but I need a fix.

When I was making the bones, I messed with the scaling to get the proper height and width of the avatar, so that may have messed something up.

But now I need **serious help** trying to find a way to reverse the weird bone scaling. Maybe that'll fix the issue.

Please, if you can, try to help me with this. I'm completely lost and already spent 3 hours watching tutorials for THIS to happen, and I don't want to undo everything (but will as a last resort.)

Thank you SO much in advance.

Comment: Apply the scale in Object mode (Ctrl A > Scale). If you need to scale the bones, do it in Edit mode, not Object mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely, you are right about "messed with scaling". Eventually, you need to apply the scale (or all transforms) of your mesh, because a child object (your mesh) will inherit all transforms of the parent mesh (your Armature) **on top of its own transforms**. As long as the base mesh has "zero shift", this is normally a good thing (makes your rig work), but with different scalings etc., things get a little weird:

[image: Apply Mesh Scale]

**But wait!** To avoid further problems, it might be good to "reset" the Rig by:

1.) either clearing the parent-child relation of the Armature... Then apply Scale, then re-parent:

[image: Clear Parent]

2.) Or you could try to temporarily disable the Armature Modifier, then Apply Scale (Quicker way, and non-destructive... Not sure if this really works, though)

[image: Disable Armature]

Let us know if this solved your Problem. If not, please add the .blend file to your Question so we can look into it further.